# How to specify buildSrc folder?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Is there any way to specify the root for `buildSrc` folder manually?

I saw there is ticket which is opened for 3 years (https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2816).

Does Gradle have this feature now?

Answer (score 4):

There's a "trick" to customize the `buildSrc` path. Just create a symlink (symbolic link) in the root dir to the `buildSrc` directory.

```
> cd /path/to/project
> ln -s ./local/path/to/builSrc builSrc
```

This will create a symlink and if you sync gradle now it will correctly pick up the `buildSrc` folder. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

- `root/gradle-plugins/build.gradle` - Builds the `gradle-plugins` project
- `root/gradle-plugins/src/main/groovy/foo/MyPlugin.groovy` - Example plugin
- `root/build.gradle` - Builds all the other projects (except for `gradle-plugins`). These "other" projects can reference `gradle-plugins` dependencies by `GAV` (group/artifact/version) eg `"foo:gradle-plugins:$version"`
- `root/settings.gradle` - `includeBuild 'gradle-plugins'` to create a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) of the two seperate builds

If you want the same version across the two builds, you could use [this trick](https://github.com/uklance/tiny-ioc/blob/master/build.gradle#L12)

Comment: Thanks, I will try sour suggestion